# strange Datetime::setDate() behaviour

Tags: php, datetime

I need a little help to look for any possible misconfiguration of the server or php, because I have a strange behaviour of DateTime's "setDate" method:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2016-01-01 23:59:59');
$datetime->setDate(2016, 2, 28);
print_r($datetime);

/*
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2016-01-28 23:59:59
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
date should actually be february!
*/
```

Well, at least it is consistent, because, when I set date to march (3) the result is february (2).

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2016-01-01 23:59:59');
$datetime->setDate(2016, 3, 28);
print_r($datetime);

/*
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2016-02-28 23:59:59
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
date should actually be march!
*/
```

In PHP default timezone is set

```
// "Europe/Berlin"
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

The Server is currently running with

```
php version 5.3.2 (unfortunately i cannot upgrade)
```

Server time is set accurately and the timezone is also Europe/Berlin.

Can someone please help me / advice me what I could do or check else?

Comment: I initially thought it was yet another DSL question caused by PHP date functions being too smart but then I tried your code and I simply [cannot reproduce the issue at all](https://3v4l.org/Ne2qi). Is this 100% real code? What are your system specs?

Comment: Sorry, I always forget the *+ unsupported versions* button. Please check the [updated demo](https://3v4l.org/nPsle). All I can think is that your internal date database is corrupted or something.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is really what happens on that server (in some virtual test machines it works flawlessly). Do you know a way to check the internal date database?

Comment: One more thing: try using `$datetime->format('c')` to inspect date variables rather than `print_r`. I remember having found a bug where `print_r` would not show actual contents.

Comment: @Ryo : I just tested your code on both http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ (for different versions of PHP) as well as on my laptop (also `Europe/Berlin` and PHP 5.x), and I'm getting the expected results. So I can confirm that the code you're using isn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: Uh, PHP 5.3, you should consider upgrading to a supported version - if you now have that datetime issue or not.

Comment: [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.installation.php) says: *The latest version of the timezone database can be installed via PECL's » [timezonedb](http://pecl.php.net/get/timezonedb)*. I've never done it. I also find it very strange that's the root of such problem.

Comment: Well, as strange as it is, I found a workaround. It feels a bit like Windows, but I get the expects results.

When I re-instantiate the DateTime-class to the variable $datetime it somehow works. I have absolutely no clue why, but...who cares!(?)

Answer (score 1):

As for the strange behavior I found a strange workaround. I think and hope others won't get this error (see answers to the question), but just in case:

You need to re-instantiate the DateTime-Class to the variable. Please don't ask me why! f-,-

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$datetime = new DateTime('2016-01-01 23:59:59');

$datetime->setDate(2016, 2, 28);
print_r($datetime);

/*
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2016-02-28 23:59:59
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
)
*/
```